# How write regular expression extra?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a  little help with using regular expression. I need check text consist only simbols, numbers and simbols _ - ( ) : , . ? / + * = « » % @ # $

I try:

```
if(preg_match("/^[А-Яа-яa-zA-Z0-9()-_«»%@#\s]+$/", $title) {
    //success
} else {
    //error     
}
```

It not working.

Comment: What's not working? What is your input?

Comment: Do you mean _letters_, numbers, and symbols?

Comment: Place the hyphen at the end of the character class. `"/^[ёЁА-Яа-яa-zA-Z0-9()_«»%@#\s-]+$/"` and add `ёЁ`

Comment: don't forget to escape `-`

Comment: @Lashane: No need to escape it if it is at the end or start of the character class (what I suggest).

Comment: I input text with @ simbol, and it display "error"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right, but later next developer will add one symbol to the end and everything is broken again, I prefer to escape it always and then don't think about it ever

Comment: @Lashane: Then, it is another "developer". :(

Comment: also text with # simbol do not pass expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul fix the regex as

```
'/^[ёЁА-Яа-яa-zA-Z0-9()_«»%@#\s-]+$/'
```

You might also want to *escape the hyphen* if another "developer" may add up more symbols to the regex and ruin it (as [Lashane mentions in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060164/how-write-regular-expression-extra/37060247#comment61667525_37060164)).

Two main points:

- `ё` and `Ё` were missing from the `а-яА-Я` range
- `-` between `)` and `_` created a range allowing all uppercase letters and some symbols:

[image]

See the **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB7jU0/1)**.